# SQL Server 2008 - why is performance WORSE with xml index?

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008

It's crazy, but query performance is about 50% WORSE after I add a primary XML index to my xml field.

Here's what I'm doing.

- I have a table containing an XML field ActivityStepLog (contains LogData, XML)
- I generate sample data to insert into this table by running the following

  INSERT INTO dbo.ActivityStepLog (
   LogGUID
   ,LogContextID
   ,LogTypeID
   ,LogSourceName
   ,LogContent
   ,LogDate
   ,CreateDate
   ,CreatedBy
  )
  select
   LogGUID         = newid()
   ,LogContextID   = newid()
   ,LogTypeID      = 2
   ,LogSourceName  = 'test test test'
   ,LogContent     = (SELECT top 1 * FROM  ##SampleData SampleData1 where DecisionLogID = SampleData.DecisionLogID FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS, ROOT('BusinessRule') )
   ,LogDate        = current_timestamp
   ,CreateDate     = current_timestamp
   ,CreatedBy      = 'test create by'
  from ##SampleData SampleData

SampleData has 100,000 rows, I run it in a loop 5 times so end up with 500,000 rows.

- The LogContent field will end up having data such as the following:

  -2147483643
     0569281A-D1A3-49E3-9E68-BCAC62E2C1C3
     1016
     2
     0
     -2147483495
     1
     2009-05-18T11:47:00
     none

(sorry, not sure if this will be formatted properly - it's just basically a short set of elements).

And then I just run a very simple sql  -

```
SELECT *
FROM ActivityStepLog
WHERE LogContent.value('(/BusinessRuleDecisionLog/SampleData1/DecisionLogID)[1]', 'int') = -2147483535
```

Before creating the primary xml index on LogContent, it takes 8 seconds, after, it takes about 12 seconds.  I've cleaned out cache, etc (DROPCLEANBUFFERS and FREEPROCCACHE ),  it doesn't seem to affect the proportions though it does affect the overall time.

Here's my statistics:

WITH xml index
Table 'xml_index_nodes_325576198_256000'. Scan count 1000000, logical reads 3517272, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'ActivityStepLog'. Scan count 1, logical reads 71694, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

With OUT xml index

(5 row(s) affected)
Table 'ActivityStepLog'. Scan count 1, logical reads 71694, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

So, the logical reads are much less withOUT the xml index.  I tried adding ALL the available secondary indexes, that didn't improve performance over having a primary xml index.

I'll be doing some more research on this, but I would really appreciate any pointers or  comments.

thanks,
Sylvia

Comment: Because you need a secondary index in addition to the primary one - for path IIRC

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but as I mentioned in my post, I did add all the available secondary xml indexes, but did not see any performance increase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From doing more research on this - it appears that for UNTYPED xml fields, at least in my test case, the xml indexes degrade performance.  This appears to be different for typed xml, though I didn't look into it much.

One thing that DID improve performance tremendously (thank you for the idea to wBob on the msdn sql xml forum!) was to create a full text index on the xml field.  I got subsecond performance at that point.  I also included an xml filter as well for accuracy.

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.ActivityStepLog
WHERE 
   CONTAINS (LogContent, '-2147483535')
   and LogContent.value('(/BusinessRuleDecisionLog/SampleData1/DecisionLogID)[1]', 'int') = -2147483535
```

I sill need to research whether this fits all my filtering needs, but so far it looks good.

Sylvia